# Base test case class for python unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a pile of objects "implementing" the same "interface". There are a few common behaviors that they all should exhibit, and that I thus want to test for in all those classes.

I was thinking of having an abstract base test case with the common stuff that is then derived from by specific test cases. There is at least one abstract method in this base test class that is called from the base class itself and needs to be defined in derivatives. I'm not sure how to call the method defined in the derivative from the base class though. If I do self.abstract_method, it'll say the method is not defined. How can I call this method?

If there is a better way of achieving my test goals here that does not involve inheritance, I'd be happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 3):

### Using inheritance

```
import cPickle
import pickle
import unittest

class TestPickleBase:
    def test_dumps_loads(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.pickle_impl.loads(self.pickle_impl.dumps('a')), 'a')

class TestCPickle(unittest.TestCase, TestPickleBase):
    pickle_impl = cPickle

class TestPickle(unittest.TestCase, TestPickleBase):
    pickle_impl = pickle

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### Using [pytest](http://pytest.org/)

```
import cPickle
import pickle

import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('pickle_impl', [pickle, cPickle])
def test_dumps_loads(pickle_impl):
    assert pickle_impl.loads(pickle_impl.dumps('a')) == 'a'
```

---

```
import cPickle
import pickle

import pytest

@pytest.fixture(params=[pickle, cPickle])
def pickle_impl(request):
    return request.param

def test_dumps_loads(pickle_impl):
    assert pickle_impl.loads(pickle_impl.dumps('a')) == 'a'
```

Comment: I'd like to stick with the build in unittest for now. The inheritance approach you posted here is what I actually did initially, and then moved away from since my IDE was saying it did not know about the assert functions in the base class. Apparently the code runs though. Is there any way to make it clear to static analysis tools that nothing is going wrong here? Ideally in such a way that they can tell me which assert methods are available (and thus provide autocompletion and whatnot).

Comment: Your IDE is complaining because the mixin class `TestPickleBase` uses a method that it does not have. You can fix it by inheriting the `unittest.TestCase` in the `TestPickleBase` class and then inherit just the `TestPickleBase` in the `TestCPickle` and `TestPickle` (leave out the `unittest.TestCase`).

Comment: @Viktor Kerkez: That doesn't work because Python's built-in unittest will try to run tests in all classes that derive from `unittest.TestCase`, even abstract classes where you don't want it to run them, leading to errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a blank version of the method in your abstract classes to avoid being told the method is not defined as so:

```
class AbstractClass(object):

    def abstract_method(self):
        pass

class ConcreteClass(AbstractClass):

    def abstract_method(self):
        # Insert logic here.
```

Comment: If I call abstract_method from AbstractClass, it is still just going to call the "implementation" there. So if I just put "pass", I'll not get an error, but it won't do what I want it to do either.

Comment: If you have an object of type ConcreteClass it will call the implementation specified by that class, regardless of where the call is made from. We use this technique quite often with no issue even when calling that method from the abstract super class